# R: how do I create categories efficiently from a vector?

Tags: r

Say I have a vector of `0` s and `1` s in R.Length of the vector is 6. So there are `2^6 = 64` combinations. My question is aside from writing 64 `ifelse` statements to return 64 different values (categories), is there a more efficient way to do this ?

```
case_classification <- function(df){
  aa      <- df["aa"]
  bb      <- df["bb"]
  cc      <- df["cc"]
  dd      <- df["dd"]
  ee      <- df["ee"]
  ff      <- df["ff"]

  if(aa == 1 && bb== 0 && cc == 0 && dd == 0 && ee == 0 && ff ==0){
      return 1;
  } else if(aa == 0 && bb== 1 && cc == 0 && dd == 0 && ee == 0 && ff ==0){
      return 2;
  }else if(...){

  } ...
}
```

Comment: You can create a key value datasset and then do a merge. i..e `d1 <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(dd[strrep(letters[1:6], 2)], unique))`, create the value column `d1$value <- c(1, 2, .....)` and do a `merge` `merge(df, d1, all.x = TRUE)`

Answer (score 3):

We can do

```
d1 <- do.call(expand.grid, lapply(df[strrep(letters[1:6], 2)], unique))
d1$value <- seq_len(nrow(d1))
merge(df, d1, all.x = TRUE)
```

---

Another option is `interaction`

```
as.integer(do.call(interaction, df[strrep(letters[1:6], 2)]))
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `replicate` and `expand.grid` you can create a dictionary to look up values from. Then just match you 6 values against the dictionary.

```
n = 6
dict = Reduce(paste, expand.grid(replicate(n, 0:1, simplify = FALSE)))

set.seed(42)
d = as.data.frame(matrix(sample(0:1, 30, TRUE), ncol = 6))
transform(d, key = match(Reduce(paste, d), dict))
#  V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6 key
#1  0  1  0  0  0  1  35
#2  0  1  1  1  0  0  15
#3  0  1  0  1  0  0  11
#4  0  0  1  1  0  0  13
#5  1  1  0  1  0  0  12
```